# Showing components in same area as CytoscapeComponent from React-Cytoscape

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

This is my first time using the React-Cytoscape library, and I'm relatively new to ReactJS. I'm working on a project where I have my own components on top of the nodes and edges of a CytoscapeComponent from React-Cytoscape. However, it won't show the two components in the same area.

I've tried enclosing the two in React.Fragment and div tags:

```
<React.Fragment> 
     <CytoscapeComponent/>
     <button/>
</React.Fragment>
```

```
<div> 
     <CytoscapeComponent/>
     <button/>
<div>
```

but neither work. Instead, the button comes below the CytoscapeComponent rather than in it after render. Also just to clarify, the CytoscapeComponent with its props is running as desired. Is there a solution to this with this library? Thanks.

Comment: Got it to work! Just had to specify position with CSS left and top properties